# Fail to connect mapStateToProps to React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am new to React + Redux and I am building a todo app.

> Property 'todos' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{
>   todos: Todo[]; }'.  TS2741

I think the problem is I fail to **connect** (react-redux) state to `TodoList`. I can confirm this because I jump from `<TodoList />` to its function component `connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList)` rather than, supposedly, `connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList)`

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-dream-w7drj?file=/src/App.tsx:712-713

I have read the react-redux doc but I did not find how to fix this.

Code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addTodo} from './index'

function AddToDo() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

  function handleInput(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setInput(e.target.value)
  }

  //dispatch to store
  function handleAddTodo() {
    addTodo(input)
    setInput('')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)}/>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleAddTodo}>
        Add todo
      </button>
    </div>
)
}

//connect
connect(null, { addTodo })(AddToDo)

//TodoList
interface Todo {
  id: number
  text: string
}

interface TodoState {
  todos: Todo[]
}

function TodoList({ todos}:{ todos: Todo[]}) {

  return (
    <ul className="todo-list">
      {todos.map((todo: Todo, index) => {
        return <Todo todo={todo} />;
        })
       }
    </ul>
  )
}

function mapStateToProps(state:TodoState) {
  return {state}
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList)

//Todo
function Todo({ todo }: { todo: Todo }) {

  return (
    <li>
      {todo}
    </li>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AddToDo />
      <TodoList /> <---------------------- Error info: Property 'todos' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ todos: Todo[]; }'.  TS2741
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your `mapStateToProps` needs to return an object. Instead of `return state.todos`, change it to `return {todos: state.todos};`

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed this issue (by  return { state } ), but the error info persist.

Comment: My mistake, your issue is with the typescript compiler erroring out?

Comment: The ts compiler returns error but I believe the root cause is I fail to connect state to the component. Added codesandbox link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your codesandbox example, I noticed a few issues.

*TLDR - [here's a working example using your code with some modifications](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-mendeleev-zd09v?file=/src/App.tsx).*

Let's walk through it step-by-step going through each component.

---

## *index.tsx*

```
const todoApp = combineReducers({
  todoReducer
});
```

should be changed to:

```
const todoApp = combineReducers({
  todos: todoReducer
});
```

**Reason**:
your entire app is under the assumption that you access todos via `state.todos`. If you kept the code the way it originally was, you'd have to access it `state.todoReducer`.

---

### *AddToDo*

```
function AddToDo() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

  function handleInput(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setInput(e.target.value)
  }

  //dispatch to store
  function handleAddTodo() {
    addTodo(input)
    setInput('')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)}/>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleAddTodo}>
        Add todo
      </button>
    </div>
)
}
```

should be changed to:

```
const addToDoConnector = connect(null, { addTodo });
// store the connect function so it can be used in typings and to create component
const ConnectedTodo = addToDoConnector(AddToDo);

function AddToDo(props: ConnectedProps<typeof addToDoConnector>) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')

  function handleInput(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setInput(e.target.value)
  }

  //dispatch to store
  function handleAddTodo() {
    props.addTodo(input)
    setInput('')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handleInput(e)}/>
      <button type="button" onClick={handleAddTodo}>
        Add todo
      </button>
    </div>
)
}
```

**Reason:**
You're importing a variable called `addTodo` at the top of the file. We need to access the AddToDo component's `addTodo` property, so it dispatches to the store.

---

### *TodoList:*

```
function TodoList({ todos}:{ todos: Todo[]}) {

  return (
    <ul className="todo-list">
      {todos.map((todo: Todo, index) => {
        return <Todo todo={todo} />;
        })
       }
    </ul>
  )
}

function mapStateToProps(state:TodoState) {
  return { state }
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList)
```

should be changed to:

```
// store the connect function so it can be used in typings and to create component
const todoListConnector = connect(mapStateToProps);
const ConnectedTodoList = todoListConnector(TodoList);

function TodoList({todos}: ConnectedProps<typeof todoListConnector>) {
  return (
    <ul className="todo-list">
      {todos.map((todo: Todo, index) => {
        return <Todo todo={todo} />;
        })
       }
    </ul>
  )
}

function mapStateToProps(state:TodoState) {
  return state;
}
```

**Reason:**
Your `mapStateToProps` was wrapping your state in a property called `state`. i.e. if your state is `{todos: []}`, it's changing it to `{state: { todos: [] } }`.

---

### *Todo*

```
//Todo
function Todo({ todo }: { todo: Todo }) {

  return (
    <li>
      {todo}
    </li>
  )
}
```

should be changed to:

```
//Todo
function Todo({ todo }: { todo: Todo }) {
  return <li>{todo.text}</li>;
}
```

**Reason:**

Todo is an object. We'd want to render the object's text.

---

### *App*

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AddToDo />
      <TodoList />
      </div>
  );
}
```

should be changed to:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ConnectedTodo />
      <ConnectedTodoList />
      </div>
  );
}
```

**Reason:**
Calling `connect` will not change the underlying component. You need to store that value in either a variable or have a dedicated file and `export` it.

---

Let me know if you have any other questions. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified the code as above. The new error on `function TodoList({ todos }: ConnectedProps<typeof connector>) ` is `Property 'todos' does not exist on type '{ state: TodoState; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>'`. This does not make sense to me because `state` has property `todos`. I am confused.

Comment: I see that you have a codesandbox example, I'll modify my answer and get back to you

Comment: @JohnHass I've updated your example and added explanations for the changes.

Comment: Awesome! That really helps me out.

Answer (score -1):

Check here working example with some modification
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-q-49657627-x7f0k?file=/src/App.tsx)